# It is possible to call a method with no parameters on this simple subscribe?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

- ***A SHORT DESCRIPTION***

Im using an observable on my code, i want to keep it **clean as posible** and i need to call `detectChanges()` method to update `*ngIf=` on html.

- ***QUESTION***

Is there any way to call `detectChanges()` method on `subscribe()` similar to the example below?

### Example (not working because overload):

---

```
this.subscriptions.add(
  this._hotelEffect
    .getHotel()
    .pipe(map(this.createHotel))
    .subscribe(this._changes.detectChanges)
);
```

### My best resolution at the moment:

---

```
this.subscriptions.add(
  this._hotelEffect
    .getHotel()
    .pipe(
      map((resp) => {
        this.createHotel(resp);
        this._changes.detectChanges();
      })
    )
    .subscribe()
);
```

Comment: Why are you collecting subscriptions? You want to cancel them on ngDestory?

Comment: yes, i got unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy

Comment: Do it more clean way using takeUntil()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you mean?

```
this.subscriptions.add(
  this._hotelEffect
    .getHotel()
    .pipe(map(this.createHotel.bind(this)))
    .subscribe(()=>this._changes.detectChanges())
);
```

assuming that `this.createHotel` can consume a return type of `getHotel()`

> i want to keep it clean as posible and i need to call

If this is really the case, then I would do it like this

```
  this._hotelEffect
    .getHotel()
    .subscribe((resp) => {
        this.createHotel(resp);
        this._changes.detectChanges();
      });
```

Also since you have stated that you collect subscriptions to cancel them on component destruction - there is a better and cleaner way to do it using `takeUntil` operator

```
  //field 
  private onDestroy=new Subject();
  ngOnDestroy(){ onDestroy.next();onDestroy.complete()}
   
  //and then with ANY observable in the component
  this._hotelEffect
    .getHotel()
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy))
    .subscribe((resp) => {
        this.createHotel(resp);
        this._changes.detectChanges();
      });
```

Comment: now Angular give me no errors, but the changes are not detected now, idk, because
the callback work, i tried `.subscribe(()=>console.log('test))` and it works, maybe i must put `detectChanges()` method on map, after `createHotel()` call

Comment: Both of  my snippets should work exactly the same way. As for your question - it is done in that order. first create then detect changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
One last question: isnt a bad practise not using the `.pipe()` method and operators to do calls and process data?

Comment: It depends on the operation. For example mapping x->y is always fine as it is a basic of functional programming to have deterministic input and output on every step on the pipeline. Usually I do heavylifting in the `subscribe` so at the very end of the pipeline. This is where I update component state as well. If your operators have side effects that this is considered a bad practice. The exception in my case is `finalize` operator as it is called always, even if pipe breaks. I use it to eg update `inProgress` flags

Comment: So as long as there are no side effects, its fine and safe to use any operator in the pipe